# How to write LESS specific to a controller/page in angular with ES6

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

In Angular 2, we have `styleUrls`, in Angular 1.X, we have something like this:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/some/route/1', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', 
            controller: 'Partial1Ctrl',
            css: 'css/partial1.css'
        })
        .when('/some/route/2', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html',
            controller: 'Partial2Ctrl'
        })
        .when('/some/route/3', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/partial3.html',
            controller: 'Partial3Ctrl',
            css: ['css/partial3_1.css','css/partial3_2.css']
        })
}]);
```

but Using BabelJS & WebPack, which is using Angular1.X with ES6 syntax, I don't know how to write **LESS** specific to a page/folder/controller, that only apply to one template,

I tried data: { css : 'some css url'} and

```
export default function routes($stateProvider) {
  'ngInject';
  $stateProvider
    .state('content', {
      url: '/content/:appId/:template/:device',
      template: require('./content.html'),
      controller: ContentController,
      controllerAs: 'content',
      css: './content.less'
    });
}
```

Still didn't work.

Please advise, if you need more info, please let me know.

Comment: My understanding is that less has to be compiled into actual css before it's usable. So point at the output css.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship Tried, not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to write styles with `less` preprocessor you should build them first and then use output filenames in route config.

If you are using Webpack, it would look like:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/app.js', //don't forget to build your js
    partial1: './src/partials/partial1.less',
    partial2: './src/partials/partial2.less',
    // and so on ...
  },
};
```

Resulting files will be in your output directory. You should point links to them:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/some/route/1', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', 
        controller: 'Partial1Ctrl',
        css: 'partial1.css'
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

I am curious, where are you getting the `css` property of the state from? It doesn't exist in the API

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider

AngularJS 1.x does not have the css encapsulation feature that is available in Angular2.

Comment: They're probably using [Angular Route Styles](https://github.com/tennisgent/angular-route-styles). I missed that they weren't using ng-route. They probably need to modify angular route styles to listen for whatever events are available. Note that this is more of a comment than an answer, so I'm downvoting. If you delete it, I think both of us will get the rep back.

Comment: In the question the original poster is using `$stateProvider` to create routes. This is part of  `uiRouter` and not `ngRouter`. angular-route-styles integrates with `ngRouter` but not `uiRouter`. So my answer still holds true and correct.

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't hold true or that it's not correct. It's just not an answer--it's a question. So it needs to be a comment, to ask the user to clarify their question.